# Need to know how to send Rtp packet to vlc from reading H265 video

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtp, h.265

I am trying to send the rtp packet to vlc to play h265 mp4 file i have derived the packet formation from ffmpeg source code

```
      uint8_t nal_type = (buf[0] >> 1) & 0x3F;
            /*
             * create the HEVC payload header and transmit the buffer as fragmentation units (FU)
             *
             *    0                   1
             *    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
             *   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
             *   |F|   Type    |  LayerId  | TID |
             *   +-------------+-----------------+
             *
             *      F       = 0
             *      Type    = 49 (fragmentation unit (FU))
             *      LayerId = 0
             *      TID     = 1
             */
            s->buf[0] = 49 << 1;
            s->buf[1] = 1;

            /*
             *     create the FU header
             *
             *     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
             *    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
             *    |S|E|  FuType   |
             *    +---------------+
             *
             *       S       = variable
             *       E       = variable
             *       FuType  = NAL unit type
             */
            s->buf[2]  = nal_type;
            /* set the S bit: mark as start fragment */
            s->buf[2] |= 1 << 7;
```

but i am geting a scrambled image only like the following
[image]

all i can see is one still scrambled image.i am adding some header in the code for time stamp and other thing and i am packing the buf from 5 position excluding start code

Answer (score 0):

```
s->buf[0] = 49 << 1;
```

writes to the whole byte. From your description, you would need to write only those 3 bits. I'd expect this to work:

```
s->buf[0] &= ~14; // 14 is 1110b. unset those bits
s->buf[0] |= 49 << 1; // 'or' in your value
```

you'll need the same fix for the second and third byte.

Comment: yes i have tried like this to be excat 
           `int nal_type = (buf[0] & 0x7E) >> 1;
            h265Header[0] = (buf[0] & 0x81) | (49<<1); // FU Indicator; Type = 49
            h265Header[1] = buf[1];
            h265Header[2] = (0x80 | nal_type);`